# Laravel 5.4.3 session is not working on new request

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am using jQuery Ajax function to validate user and create session. In laravel controller i have the following code.

```
        if( isset( $_POST['email'] ) )
        {
            $email      = $_POST['email'];
            $password   = $_POST['password'];

            $results =  DB::table('table')->where([
                            ['school_email', '=', $email ],
                            ['school_password', '=', $password],
                        ])->get() ;

            if( $results -> count() ==  0 )
            {
                echo json_encode( array('data' => '0' ) ); exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $user =  $results[0] ;
                session(['users' => $user ]);
                $request    ->  session()   ->  put('two', 'test');
                echo json_encode( array( 'data' => '1' ) );
                exit;
    }
```

Session is set when i print it after setting session variable.But when i refresh the page or redirect user to another url. session is coming as empty variable.
I am using file session with default settings and directory (storage) is writable. I did change server.php to index.php and copied htaccess from public directory to root just to access my local site with out writing public in url. e.g http://localhost/site2/login before it was

http://localhost/site2/public/login

Comment: "_just to access my local site with out writing public in url_" If you [set up Laravel the correct way](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation) there is no need to "_change server.php to index.php_"

Comment: I saw this method too on a forum followed by people. do you think it is causing issue in sessions?

Answer (score 0):

We need to   use $request    ->  session()   ->  save(); after assigning value to session variable. Strange it was not pointed any where in document.